# ASP.NET - Receiving HTTP POST data in Forms Authentication's loginUrl (from an external App)

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, http-post

I need to pass some data from a classic ASP application to my ASP.NET app using the POST method (can't use GET sorry) in a form.

This doesn't seem to work if my action is the target aspx page but my ASP.NET app is using forms authentication, because it looks like somewhere in the pipeline my data is lost, given that the Request.Form collection is null in the Page_Load method of my login page.

If I disable forms authentication, the target page receives the posted data without a problem.

Do you know how can I work-around this problem? When or where could I obtain this data?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possibility might be to transfer the posted headers into a session object you maintain in your ASPX side that would then be killed once its purpose is complete.

```
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    // Code that runs when a new session is started
    SortedList sList = new SortedList();
    foreach (string key in HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.Keys)
    {
        sList.Add(key, HttpContext.Current.Request.Form[key]);
    }
    Session.Add("myList", sList);

}
```

Comment: Sounds like a plausible workaround, I had to remove "forms authentication" from my project and use my own implementation, but I'll keep an eye on the post to see if your answer is the best. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can you just unprotect the single page that's the target of the POST?

In your web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <location path="MyPostHandlingPage.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Well I think this defies the purpose of using the authentication in the first place, at least in my case.

Comment: Sorry about that. I figured protection for the whole site except the integration point would be good enough.

Comment: @murki It seems like you disregarded a good answer here. You can post to an unprotected page that simply copies the posted data to some target (session, request context, database, ..etc), and then automatically redirects to your protected page.

Answer (score 0):

The 2 possible way to transfer data between asp to aspx is

1. using Session, Via SQL DB (Ref. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479313.aspx
2. Using QueryString in a intermediate ASP page as below.

Your 1st ASP page : sample.asp

```
<% language="VBScript"%>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" action="process.asp" method="post">
    <div>
        &nbsp;<input name="Text1" id="Text1" type="text" />
        <input id="Submit2" type="submit" value="submit" /></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Your Intermediate page : process.asp

```
<%@ language="vbscript"%>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form2">
    <%response.Write(Request.Form("Text1"))
     %>
    <%response.Redirect("default3.aspx?icontent=" & Request.Form("Text1"))  %>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Your ASPX code page : Default.aspx

```
public partial class Default3 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write(Request.QueryString["icontent"].ToString());
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm aware of this, I was wondering if there's no way of use POST (hence my no GET comment) to pass data around, given that I can't change the way the ASP app is coded (and is data that doesn't need to be seen in the query string). DB is definitely an overkill for a simple problem. And even the (third?) POST option work, unless I implement forms authentication, then my data loses its way.

Comment: but this is how we can share data between asp and aspx in most of the production scripts too as i hav worked. but everything is based on the requirement, if it really need then we have to look for the workaround, but i wonder there wont be any available as of now to my little knowldege. :)